# How to install Cucumber-JVM on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, cucumber-jvm

I have searched all over the internet but a newbie on java I cant figure out how to simply install Cucumber-jvm on Eclipse.

What files do I need to download? 
I already installed Eclipse. What do I need to do to get Cucumber-JVM on Eclipse?

Answer (score 18):

If you mean the Cucumber plugin for Eclipse you can do this by:

1. Open Eclipse, Click Help → Install New Software.
2. Click on the "Add" button at the right side of 'Work with' field.
3. Give the Name (say, cucumber-eclipse) and input the URL 'https://cucumber.github.io/cucumber-eclipse/update-site' at Location field -> Click OK.
4. Check the box 'Cucumber Eclipse Plugin'.
5. Untick 'Contact all update sites during install...'.
6. Click <kbd>Next</kbd>.
7. Follow the instructions at the prompts.

Comment: When I type cucumber in the 'Work with' field, nothing happens - I need to just paste the URL you listed directly into the 'Work with' field, and them I am in business.

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber-JVM isn't an Eclipse library or plugin. You can download it in a variety of ways (I find Maven the easiest), and include it in your code.

Comment: Yes, Maven is the easiest way

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't you try this plugin? I think it should be greater for your cucumber coding than the official plugin: [BecauseCucumber](https://becausetesting.github.io/becausecucumber/)

Installation steps are there: [BecauseCucumber Installation](http://becausetesting.github.io/becausecucumber/install.html)

Comment: cucumber-people looked promising, however the install failed for me :(

Comment: Is it possible to install from "Eclipse Marketplace..."?

Comment: I got the following error after installing CucumberPeople and restarting Eclipse: *'gem' is not recognized as an internal or external command...*

Comment: @RiponAlWasim, you can install it from this update site: http://becausetesting.github.io/becausecucumber/ ,but i had not uploaded it into eclipse marketplace.

Comment: @rob, That's the expected result ,as you had not installed Ruby in your host ,because the plugin try to find Ruby environment in your host, you can ignore this message. also i will remove this message in later version. check the new plugin i had refactored: http://becausetesting.github.io/becausecucumber/  ,add more wonderful features .

Comment: @nilesh, thanks . I'm trying to refactor new version for this plugin ,should be greater than before.

Comment: @Alter.hu Is there a way to use it without having to install Ruby? I use Cucumber-JVM, not Ruby.  The Cucumber plugin for Eclipse does not require you to install Ruby.

Comment: @rob,Yes. you no need to install Ruby. it's just a warning message to let you know that you need to install Ruby firstly when your project has Ruby feature. please ignore it .that's fine.

Comment: Thank you  Alter.hu

Comment: The above link doesn't work and I couldn't find it via searching the web. I think Because Cucumber is dead.

Answer (score 1):

**Steps to Install Cucumber on Eclipse**

- Open Eclipse
- Help > Install New Software > Add
- Name: Cucumber
- Location: https://cucumber.github.io/cucumber-eclipse/update-site
- Then hit Add button
- You will see Cucumber Eclipse Plugin. Check the box
- Hit Finish button
- Then hit Install Anyway
- Then hit Restart.

Answer (score 0):

You can find how to install Cucumber-jvm in the [Cucumber documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/installation/java/)

In addition, you'll need the [Eclipse plugin](https://cucumber.io/docs/tools/java/#eclipse).