# How to generate steps of cucumber features in STS (Eclipse)?

Tags: java, cucumber

I have seen it, and i have tried to follow its steps to generate the steps of feature file. Here is my dependencies in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And i have defined the runner class as below:

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"})
public class RunCukesTest {
}
```

and the feature file is located in `src/features` in the project:

The problem is, when i `right click on the feature file-> Run as-> Cucumber`

**Nothing happens.**

**I expect that, the cucumber runner runs, and gives me the steps**

So, what is wrong?

Feature is:

Feature: Title of your feature
 I want to submit data into registeration form

```
Scenario: Register into the forum
Given I want to register into the main forum
When I enter name
    And I enter passwrod
    And I repeat the password
    And I enter username
    And I enter email
Then I click the submit
```

Comment: First try running runner class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't need that `RunCukesTest` at all.The point was to install the `Cucumber-jvm` plugin on STS, and it generates the steps very easily. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538854/how-to-install-cucumber-jvm-on-eclipse) question was also very useful.

Additionally, to run a feature file in Eclipse, you should

1. open the file
2. Right click on it
3. Rus as
4. 1 Cucumber Feature