# Selenium Cucumber/BDD framework

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd

login.feature file is not correctly configured. When i user 'When', 'Then' keywords then selenium does not recognize them.

```
Feature: Application Login

Scenario: Home page default login
Given User is on Netbanking landing page
When User login into application with username and password
Then Home page  is populated
And Cards are displaying
```

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Can you provide more information? Like what exactly your problem is? Bind to step definitions? Code behind not generated? Keywords not recognized? Are necessary references added?

Comment: Which programming language are you using to define the steps? Are you using an IDE, and if so which one?

Comment: @StefanZivkovic Please refer the screenshot attached. I am configuring a cucumber (BDD) framework where feature file is not correctly configured. As a result, **all the keywords (Given, when, then) in feature file are not recognized** All the dependencies added but if you want to see them, i can share.

Comment: @GregBurghardt i am working on selenium + java. Please refer the screenshot and comments above

Comment: @Shaman Gumber I see you are working in Eclipse. I am not familiar with that IDE. I guess you have to google more and investigate what setting or reference your are missing.

Comment: See [How to install Cucumber-JVM on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14538854/3092298) and [Configure Eclipse with Cucumber](https://www.toolsqa.com/cucumber/configure-eclipse-cucumber/).

Answer (score 0):

More information is needed. 
'When', 'Then' keywords are not recognized by ... Selenium or Gherkin (Cucumber)?
Could you please provide a sample of our StepDefinition ?